# Insert a picture in Texmaker

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert a picture using the command `\includegraphics` and it does not appear anything in the document. The image I am trying to insert is in JPG format and it is inside the same folder of the TEX document. When I am trying to insert it I have this error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You're missing `\usepackage{graphicx}` before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you have missed a few lines while defining the figure. I would normally do it as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{elsarticle} % article for Elsevier
\usepackage{graphicx} % need this package

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp] % htbp stand for "here", "top", "bottom", "page"
\includegraphics[scale=1]{yourfigure.jpg} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Try using these lines and also by including the graphics package `\usepackage{graphicx}` after the `\documentclass` command and you should be fine. Also make sure you are using pdflatex and that name of the figure is exactly matched. I hope this helps.

Thank you,
Harsha.

Answer (score 0):

A few things which usually help solve this issue :

1. Include the `graphicx` package

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   ```
2. If your images are located in the same folder as the tex file, you do not have to include a graphics path. But if that is not the case, you will have to. The method I prefer is to have a folder inside the folder where you .tex files are. If that folder is called fig, this is how you enter it:

   ```
   \graphicspath{ {./fig/} }
   ```
3. Try running pdflatex instead of latex. Works pretty well for me.
4. Change the file extension formats to lowercase. Simply changing the extension from .JPG to .jpg did the trick for me once.

Hope this helps!